# Сделать js код нечитаемым

Tags: javascript

Я хочу, чтобы исходный js код, при публикации был нечитаемым и чтобы нельзя было расшифровать. Можно ли вообще такое сделать? Если да, то как?

Comment: Простой минификации кода вам не достаточно?

Comment: Это как?  Что это?

Comment: https://www.obfuscator.io/

Comment: Понял, спасибо)

Comment: нечитаемым, зачем? предотвратить отладку таким образом все равно нельзя, только усложнить.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ могу предположить, для того, чтобы никто не смог внутрь залезть и поменять что-то (например ограничения, с которых возьмется монетизация).

Comment: тогда уж посмотрите на webassembly :)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц все равно, как бы код не был обфусцирован, его можно поставить на брейкпоинт и пройти весь по шагам, да это может быть не быстро.. в общем , ни при каких обстоятельствах, нельзя верить клиенту, все ключевые моменты надо так или иначе проверять или держать на сервере

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Я бы хотел посмотреть на человека, который будет проходить по шагам код, обработанный [jsfuck](http://www.jsfuck.com/) :)

Answer (score 0):

Вообще gulp например для сжатия вашего кода на лету подойдет. Но требует время на изучение и настройку.

Для начинающего не плохой вариант писать код используя какую-нибудь визуальную прогу для сборки. Я например использую prepros https://prepros.io/ на мой взгляд очень удобно.

Для примера настройка автосборки выглядит вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: препрос же просто минифицирует js но не обфусцирует же ...да ?

Comment: @MaximLensky все верно. Но этого достаточно на мой взгляд. Код все равно не редактируемый получается. Хотя там настроек сжатия приличное количество может есть и то что нужно. Плюс в том, что один раз настроил и он работает сам по себе с любым количеством проектов.